# Zipping files in browser and sending it through POST

Tags: javascript, php, zip

I'm building a webapp which sends emails, but before sending it, **it rehosts the images and updates the scr's pointing to the server**. The current approach is sending a zip file with a .htm and a couple of .jpg, which the system parse and host the appropiate files.

I want to bypass the zip file, so the user can select a bunch of files and send them through POST. The problem is that the amount of files is random and showing a lot of file input boxes would look terrible (plus selecting everyfile would be boring). I was thinking of using the folder upload feature of HTML5 **but it doesn't work on every browser**.

My current approach is zipping the files **in the browser** and then sending the zip trough POST. I found two libraries for this: jszip and zip.js. jszip seems to be broken, because if you use [one of their examples](http://stuk.github.io/jszip/documentation/examples/read-local-file-api.html), it fails no matter which file I input.

Zip.js works perfectly, but I can only manage to download the generated zip through a "blob". I modified the [demo1](http://gildas-lormeau.github.io/zip.js/demos/demo1.html) to my needs, but **I only can output a blob url**.

Is there any way to **access that blob data**? If possible, I could populate a hidden input field through jquery with this data, base64 encoded, and decode it in PHP.

One of the solutions I found is using a XMLHttpRequest to that blob, which for some reason only returns a malformed zip.

Any ideas?

Comment: Looks like you're missing something: How will this zip file be produced? By having the user select a bunch of files.... by presenting a bunch of file selection inputs, which you've already said you don't want because it'll be messy. And note that you'll gain almost NOTHING in space savings by using the zip, since images tend to compress poorly or worse. At most you'll be slightly more efficient by uploading only one zip instead of multiple individual files.

Comment: Forgot to add, the demo1 of zip.js lets you select a bunch of files which each gets add to a queue. When you click download, the zip is produced. BTW, im not looking to save bandwith or anything trough the compression, I'm looking to simplify the act of uploading a bunch of files.

Comment: `<input type="file">` now supports `multiple`...

Comment: I know, but like i said in my question I'm looking for a different solution because it doesn't have legacy support for older browsers.

Comment: What browsers do you need to support ? If the browser supports blob (and FileReader to read them), I think that it will support `multiple` on `<input type="file">`.